# How to increase numbers precision in TikZ histogram

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I entered fixed point numbers in the following code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}   
\centering   
\begin{axis}[xbar,bar width=0.2cm,legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)},     xmin=0,xmax=0.8,anchor=north,legend columns=-1},ylabel={Top 6 Cases},symbolic y coords={Case$_{b3}$,Case$_{b6}$,Case$_{b4}$,Case$_{c5}$,Case$_{d1}$,Case$_{c3}$},     ytick=data,     nodes near coords,     nodes near coords align=horizontal,     ]
 \addplot coordinates {(0.6967,Case$_{b3}$) (0.69628,Case$_{b6}$) (0.69201,Case$_{b4}$) (0.66584,Case$_{c5}$) (0.65422,Case$_{d1}$) (0.65363,Case$_{c3}$)};
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

but the shown numbers in the pdf file are only 2 digits after the point, I want them to be shown as the ones in the code having the right precision.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The content of the label nodes is determined by the argument to `nodes near coords`. It defaults to `\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}`, so it uses the PGF number parser to format the numbers. By default, this rounds the values to two digits.

There are different ways to alter this. One is to set the optional argument to

```
nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed zerofill, precision=5]{\pgfplotspointmeta}},
```

Or you could use the `every node near coord` style:

```
every node near coord/.append style={
    /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill,
    /pgf/number format/precision=5
}
```

Both will lead to the same result:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}   
\centering   
\begin{axis}[
    xbar,
    enlarge x limits=0.4,
    bar width=0.2cm,
    legend style={
        at={(0.5,-0.15)},
        anchor=north,
        legend columns=-1
    },
    ylabel={Top 6 Cases},
    symbolic y coords={
        Case$_{b3}$,
        Case$_{b6}$,
        Case$_{b4}$,
        Case$_{c5}$,
        Case$_{d1}$,
        Case$_{c3}$
    },
    ytick=data, 
    nodes near coords,
    nodes near coords align=horizontal,
    every node near coord/.append style={
        /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill,
        /pgf/number format/precision=5
    }
]
\addplot coordinates {(0.6967,Case$_{b3}$) (0.69628,Case$_{b6}$) (0.69201,Case$_{b4}$) (0.66584,Case$_{c5}$) (0.65422,Case$_{d1}$) (0.65363,Case$_{c3}$)};
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you :), another question; how to change the color of the rectangles and numbers?

Comment: @microarm15: To change the colour of the bars, use `\addplot [fill=orange, draw=orange!50!black] coordinates ...`. To change the color of the numbers, use `every node near coord/.append style={black}` in the `axis` options.