# how to configure amount of the number of digits after the comma

Tags: pgfplots, nodes

I'm drawing this plot via overleaf.
This is the code:

```
\begin{figure}
\resizebox{0.5\textwidth}{!}{%  
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        symbolic x coords={FasterRCNN,Yolov5,EfficientDet,Ensemble},
        xlabel=Detector,
        ylabel=mAP,
        xtick=data,
        legend style={at={(0.75,0.35)},
            anchor=north},
        ]
        \addplot [red,mark=*, nodes near coords,every node near coord/.append style={xshift=19pt,yshift=-7pt,anchor=east,font=\footnotesize}, ultra thick]
        coordinates {(FasterRCNN,0.210) (Yolov5,0.248)
            (EfficientDet,0.256) (Ensemble,0.259)};
        \addplot [green,mark=square,nodes near coords,every node near coord/.append style={xshift=19pt,yshift=-7pt,anchor=east,font=\footnotesize}, ultra thick]
        coordinates {(FasterRCNN,0.246) (Yolov5,0.263)
            (EfficientDet,0.276) (Ensemble,0.285)};
        \addplot [blue,mark=star,nodes near coords,every node near coord/.append style={xshift=-6pt, font=\footnotesize}, ultra thick]
        coordinates {(FasterRCNN,0.269) (Yolov5,0.278)
            (EfficientDet,0.281) (Ensemble,0.292)};
        \legend{None, Resnet50, EfficientNet}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\caption{Evaluation of combination of classifier and detector in the proposed framework.}
\label{fig:mota_idf1}
\end{figure}
```

My question is how to configure amount of the number of digits after the comma ? In my case, I want it show 3 digits after the comma, eg, 0.281 instead of just 0.28

Many thanks
[image]

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111652/how-to-increase-numbers-precision-in-tikz-histogram seems relevant as well.

Comment: @Marijn problem solved thanks to your solution